# Weird texture applied

Tags: unity, 3d, textures, blender

So I applied  the baked texture (on the right side of screen shot) but it shows in this manner. What is the problem? I made the model in Blender and also the baked image. The house consists of multiple separate objects.[image: Unity screen]

[image: Model with bakedUV]

Comment: It appears as though the UVs in the geometry are not appropriate for the texture. There's an assertion at the bottom of your screen related, perhaps, to texture atlasing. That may be a hint in the direction you need to look. It may be useful if you can post an image of how the UVs are structured for the model as well.

Comment: Ok, i have added a pic of the Blender project. Please take a look.Also the 'Assertion Failed' error in unity was related to a different gameobject.

Comment: In blender it is possible to have [multiple uv's](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/layout_management.html#uv-maps-panel) for an object. I expect you created a new uvlayout when you joined the objects or baked the image, while unity is using the old layout. Does unity see multiple uv's to choose from? In blender you could delete the old layout.